# Detecting ACTION_UP / ACTION_DOWN when a ScrollView is swiped up/down

Tags: android

It is already known that when you scroll or swipe a scrollview you will get a ACTION_CANCEL event. I need to know when the ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN events occur but ACTION_CANCEL will prevent ACTION_UP / ACTION_DOWN from being issued if you continuously swipe up and down. I tried implementing onInterceptTouchEvent and even used getActionMasked but neither solution worked.

Is there someway to know when my scrollview has generated an ACTION_UP when the user releases their finger during swiping?

UPDATE:

I am apparently making some assumptions about how Android handles motion and touch events. I found the following video helpful that gives a good overview on Android's touch system and it even covers what I am doing:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI

Comment: Do you extend ScrollView?

Comment: I did extend it and overrode onInterceptTouch but as stated the ACTION_UP will not be issued once scrolling begins and you lift your finger up.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way but if can you please try some-thing like this...

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

Timer ntimer = new Timer();
MotionEvent event;

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) 
{
    checkAgain();
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}

public void checkAgain(){
    try{
        ntimer.cancel();
        ntimer.purge();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    ntimer = new Timer();
    ntimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                // ScrollView Stopped Scrolling and Finger is not on the ScrollView
            }
            else{
                // ScrollView Stopped Scrolling But Finger is still on the ScrollView
                checkAgain();
            }
        }
    },100);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.event = event; 
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to know ACTION_UP and not scrolling. I need to know when the finger leaves the screen.